# Eclipse Find Code Coverage

Tags: eclipse, emma

I would need to use Eclipse to find code coverage of a test file generated by an automated tool with respect to a certain project.

I am thinking of using the "Emma" plugin but, as the project was not originally an Eclipse one, am having some difficulties importing it. I can open individual files, but that is not of much use as I can't run the plugin then.

Any ideas? :)

Thanks!

Comment: so the real question is: How to import an existing Java Project into Eclipse??

Comment: @Simulant I guess so, I've gone through various tutorials, but the problem is when I select my project I get "no projects to import" even though all my java files are there